# Prevent folding org files opened by ediff

Tags: org-mode, hooks, ediff, local-variables

Folding gets in the way when merging two org files using ediff, so I'm trying to disable all folding in org-mode buffers created by ediff.  Non-ediff folding behavior should remain unaffected.

Naively I think that something akin to the following should work:

```
  (add-hook 'ediff-mode-hook
        (lambda ()
          (set (make-local-variable 'org-inhibit-startup-visibility-stuff) t)))
```

I'm fairly certain that this is the org variable to modify (rather than `org-startup-folded` or `org-agenda-inhibit-startup`).

I've tried various hooks to no avail (mainly `ediff-mode-hook`, `ediff-before-setup-hook`, `ediff-meta-mode-hook`, and `ediff-prepare-buffer-hook`- which is probably too late) hoping that the interned variable will be inherited.

It's quite possible that I'm using make-local-variable incorrectly; the pattern is just borrowed from what I've widely seen.

Only setting the value globally has been effective (but that's not what I'm shooting for).  Should I be (ab)using the advice mechanism?

Comment: Not sure which hook to use, but why not just a function call to `show-all` instead?  (`org-mode` is built on top of `outline-mode`, and it sounds like you always want it to show everything.)

Comment: `(add-hook 'ediff-prepare-buffer-hook 'show-all)` does the trick!  Add that as an answer, @Dan?  I'm still curious about local variables for ediff, but I think `show-all` is the best solution to my problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like your goal is to have `org-mode` files *always* show everything when in `ediff`.  The simplest solution is probably to avoid the local variables approach and just put `show-all` in the relevant hook, `ediff-prepare-buffer-hook` which is run after buffers A, B, & C are set up:

```lisp
 (with-eval-after-load 'outline
   (add-hook 'ediff-prepare-buffer-hook #'org-show-all))
```

Despite the name, `org-show-all` also works in `outline-mode` which `org-mode` is built on top of. Unlike `outline-show-all`, it shows property drawers and blocks like `#+begin_src ... #+end_src`.

`org-show-all` has been added in Org 9.1.6. In earlier versions you can use `outline-show-all` or `show-all`.

(Note, according to a comment, that `show-all` is marked obsolete in Emacs 25.1 in favor of `outline-show-all`.  The latter symbol is not bound in 24.5.)

Comment: It looks like `show-all` is defined sanely, so that it doesn't need any defensive conditions in the hook and can be safely called within non-org / non-outline modes.

Comment: Great answer. But `show-all` is marked obsolete since 25.1. Better to use `outline-show-all`, I think. (The former is just an alias for the latter.)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: thanks for the note!  I've edited the answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 4):

Another option can be found on the [worg](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-hacks.html#orgheadline96) page. The basic [idea](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/75222) is to use `ediff-select-hook` to unfold an element whenever given region is selected in ediff and folding them back in the `ediff-unselect-hook`. I am posting the code here for completeness

```lisp
;; Check for org mode and existence of buffer
(defun f-ediff-org-showhide (buf command &rest cmdargs)
  "If buffer exists and is orgmode then execute command"
  (when buf
    (when (eq (buffer-local-value 'major-mode (get-buffer buf)) 'org-mode)
      (save-excursion (set-buffer buf) (apply command cmdargs)))))

(defun f-ediff-org-unfold-tree-element ()
  "Unfold tree at diff location"
  (f-ediff-org-showhide ediff-buffer-A 'org-reveal)  
  (f-ediff-org-showhide ediff-buffer-B 'org-reveal)  
  (f-ediff-org-showhide ediff-buffer-C 'org-reveal))

(defun f-ediff-org-fold-tree ()
  "Fold tree back to top level"
  (f-ediff-org-showhide ediff-buffer-A 'hide-sublevels 1)  
  (f-ediff-org-showhide ediff-buffer-B 'hide-sublevels 1)  
  (f-ediff-org-showhide ediff-buffer-C 'hide-sublevels 1))

(add-hook 'ediff-select-hook 'f-ediff-org-unfold-tree-element)
(add-hook 'ediff-unselect-hook 'f-ediff-org-fold-tree)
```

Comment: This works really well for me, thank you!